# Three JS, InstanceMesh's Dots overlapping and Gaps

Tags: javascript, instance-methods, threejs-editor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WDAh.png)
Hi, I'm building a Globe in Three Js, and I want to have One Million InstanceMesh small transparent dots on it which I already achieved as you guys can see in the image, but there are some overlapping and small gaps between dots, is there any way I can remove it and distribute dots around the sphere perfectly so that there will be no spacing of overlapping. if I increase the size of the dots to reduce spacing, then overlapping becomes more and if I try to reduce the overlapping gaps becomes more, they are in-directly proportional to each other.

I've tried to distribute dots around the globe in many different ways like Fibonacci, grid-base, poisson disk sampling distributions but they all failed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.